# Cron for Solspace Calendar and Importer

Tags: solspace-calendar, solspace-importer, cron

Would like to setup an EE template that I can run cron jobs through. With Solspace Calendar's {exp:calendar:ics_update}, I can create a template to include selected calendars and can dynamically set different update cycles (e.g. one a week, twice a week, daily) on the template via a custom channel field for calendar_calendars.

Some calendars which we want to import from don't have ICS files or have more information on other export formats so we use Solspace Importer for these.  The only way I see setting up cron jobs for these is doing it directly and not with a template.

I think I know the answer, but would there be a way to do the same for Importer imports as Calendar imports?  If not, would be great to add a similar feature for Solspace Importer.

Answer (score 0):

Importer does not support importing Calendar entries. Only ICS files can be used for import.

I recommend submitting this as a Feature Request under the specific add-on category. It'll also give other users the option to vote up the feature request, and help us prioritize features to add in upcoming versions of this add-on. :)
http://support.solspace.com/support/discussions

As for your templates using `{exp:calendar:ics_update}`, you could use your server's `wget` command in your cron job to access the URL that contains this Calendar tag to update calendars with ICS files.

Comment: Thanks for reply.  You can import events from various formats via Importer, but they won't be automatically associated with a calendar or have date information.  That is fine.  We manually add that information later.  Each Saved Import is associated with a specific calendar.

Comment: Will check out the Feature Request section. It would be nice to have more crossover features like a way to import into the Dates & Options field for Calendar in Importer or if not possible, at least being able to preset the calendar to import to if not the actual date information.